# Does member variables gets retained by block when accessed using self

Tags: objective-c-blocks

I know that self is retained by a block if its being referenced inside a block. But if I am doing like this:

NSLog(@"%@",self.memberVariable);

Will memberVariable also be retained by the block? or only self is retained by the block?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only "variable" you are "accessing" is `self`. Blocks only "capture" local variables (`self` is considered a local variable), because those are the only variables whose lifetime is tied to scope. Properties (which are really method calls) and instance variables are always "accessed" through some other object pointer, and thus their lifetime is associated with that object's lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

The member variable also retained.According to Block programming guide,

> In a reference-counted environment, by default when you reference an
>   Objective-C object within a block, it is retained. This is true even
>   if you simply reference an instance variable of the object. Object
>   variables marked with the __block storage type modifier, however, are
>   not retained.

Comment: So, if I put a __block storage modifier on an object then will it apply to its member variables too?